# saslpasswd2: generic failure on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, sasl

I get a generic failure when I try to run:

```
saslpasswd2 username
```

This was installed by Collanet's Subversion 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I had was that the sasl executables are trying to access the sasldb file at:

```
C:\CMU\sasldb2
```

Make sure that you create the directory 
    C:\CMU

Comment: I downloaded SASL directly (without Collabnet) and I only have a structure like `\CMU\etc\sasldb2`is this fine? Also, I need to install it on D:/, are you saying that this is not possible?